# Better Exposed Filters Secondary Options Hierarchy

Tags: views

I can't find where to set the hierarchy for filters under "Secondary Exposed Form Options". I can do it without ticking the "Secondary Form" box, but after setting it it seems to get overridden.

Right now this is what I have:
[image: Right now this is what I have:]

Despite my fields being ordered like this;

```
Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed) | Settings
Content: Author uid (exposed)
Content: Post date (exposed)
```

Can anyone help me out with getting this ordered properly?